# «Совпадения»/«указатель»

Tags: синонимы, термины

Скажите, будьте добры, слышали ли вы когда-нибудь, чтобы в аппарате издания вместо термина «указатель» (имен/названий) в книгах использовали термин «совпадения»? Являются ли эти термины синонимичными?

Comment: Не могли бы Вы привести обстоятельства, при которых Вам это встретилось? Думаю, это ошибка или неверный перевод. Такого термина вообще в издательском деле не встречала. https://www.press-book.ru/library/books/EditingLiterature/par0450.html

Comment: Да, это перевод с английского в книге. Мне тоже не встречалось подобное, но вызвало сомнения.